# Convert java.util.TimeZone String to java.util.TimeZone

Tags: java, datetime

Is it possible to convert a `java.util.TimeZone` String

```
sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id=\"America/Los_Angeles\",offset=-28800000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,transitions=185,lastRule=java.util.SimpleTimeZone[id=America/Los_Angeles,offset=-28800000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,startYear=0,startMode=3,startMonth=2,startDay=8,startDayOfWeek=1,startTime=7200000,startTimeMode=0,endMode=3,endMonth=10,endDay=1,endDayOfWeek=1,endTime=7200000,endTimeMode=0]]
```

back to `java.util.TimeZone` object?

Comment: You could possibly parse the `id` out of this string and  get a new `TimeZone` object from it. But it seems like an XY problem: why do you get a string like that anyway, and why can't you use the original object or a serialization of it or an easier to parse string?

Comment: I've decided to use the "id" value of the original timezone object instead of this string. Thanks!

Comment: FYI, `TimeZone` is one of the troublesome old date-time classes that are now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes. See the classes `ZoneId` and `ZoneOffset`.

Comment: Agree with @BasilBourque. If you got the ID string (either from parsing or some other way), use `ZoneId.of(idString)`. Still easier if you got the original `TimeZone` object: `timeZoneObject.toZoneId()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part of Effective Java; Item 10:

> Provide programmatic information to all the information provided by
>   toString, or clients may try to parse the string to retrieve it.

In other words: if it is doable, don't try to parse the output of `toString`. If you are **forced** to do it (but only if really-really-really there is no other way), then you could do it:

- you have to do it with reflection (`TimeZone` is an abstract class, in the `toString` output you see that this instance is not a `ZoneInfo` but a `SimpleTimeZone`)
- you have to parse the data which you need in any of the applicable constructors and invoke it

There is no "easy solution" to "backmapping" a `toString` representation of `TimeZone` into a `TimeZone` object. (There are some APIs where you have a `fromString` method or similar, the new Java Date API is not one of them, and it shouldn't be).

Comment: I will stick to using the original TimeZone object instead of this String. This seems to add unnecessary complexity. Thank you.